# Spreading react props in tsx in typescript 2.3.1

Tags: typescript

I have some code that used to compiles fine in typescript 2.2, but fails in 2.3.1:

```ts
class Component<T extends object> extends React.Component<T, {}> {
  render() { return <div { ...this.props }></div>; }
}
```

I now get:

```ts
ERROR in ./file.tsx
(34,17): error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.
```

I suspect that this is fixed by this [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13288) (unmerged at time of writing), but in the meantime, is there a way to workaround around this issue?

Comment: This issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15420)

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar error with `typescript@2.3.2`
Here is a quick workaround: `<div { ...this.props as any }></div>`