# Spread operator with React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have a single page application with redirecting implemented as

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    Acc.isLoggedIn === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
)} />
```

)

```
export { PrivateRoute };
```

I'm trying to update it to work something like this

```
interface IPrivateRouteProps {
}

interface IPrivateRouteState {
  isAuthenticated?: boolean
}

export class PrivateRoute extends React.Component<IPrivateRouteProps, IPrivateRouteState> {
constructor(props: IPrivateRouteProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({ isAuthenticated: null });
}

componentDidMount() {
    Acc.isAuthenticated()
        .then(isAuthenticated => {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated });
        });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (<Component {...props} />)}/>
    }
    else {
        return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />)}/>
    }
}
}
```

How can I pass on the props using the spread operator in typescript?

**Update**

Needless to say, I'm not just relying to client side code for authentication.

I have already tried this but it didn't help: [Spreading react props in tsx in typescript 2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664031/spreading-react-props-in-tsx-in-typescript-2-3-1)

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Also `isAuthenticated` can only be a `boolean` or `undefined` according to `IPrivateRouteState` not null.

Comment: The error is "Cannot find name 'rest'."

Comment: Also `rest` is not defined in `PrivateRoute` so technically you're trying to spread `undefined`.

Comment: You can only use spread with an object or array

Comment: Typescript has nothing to do with it. You just forgot to define the `rest` variable

Answer (score 0):

`rest` is not defined.

Did you mean:

`return <Route {...this.props} render={(props) => (<Component {...props} />)}/>`

Comment: It just doesn't redirect when I try that.

Comment: This line:

`return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />)}/>`

Should be more like:

`return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />`